Problems with 'Makefile' in BNFC on Windows
I'm trying to use the BNFC compiler tool on my Windows laptop.
I'm following this tutorial.
I've installed all the required programs, and when I use
bnfc -m -c Calc.cf the output seems to be correct, but when I try using make (Windows make specifically), it gives the following output:
gcc -g --ansi -W -Wall -Wsign-conversion -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration  -c Absyn.c
gcc -g --ansi -W -Wall -Wsign-conversion -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration  -c Buffer.c
flex -Pcalc_ -oLexer.c Calc.l
"Calc.l", line 6: unrecognized %option: reentrant
"Calc.l", line 8: unrecognized '%' directive
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: #
"Calc.l", line 13: unknown error processing section 1
"Calc.l", line 13: unknown error processing section 1
"Calc.l", line 13: unknown error processing section 1
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: 2
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: 0
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: 0
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: 8
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: 0
"Calc.l", line 13: bad character: 9
"Calc.l", line 13: unknown error processing section 1
"Calc.l", line 14: bad character: }
make: *** [Lexer.c] Error 1

I followed this tutorial to install flex and bison. I did manage to install them, along with BNFC, but then the make command didn't work. I tried using mingw32-make.exe, but it just said 'mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'.' I then tried downloading Windows make and it gave the output in the question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
